# Is it safe update WordPress 3.4.2. to 3.5?

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress 3.4.2 site have 25 activated plugin, so Which is safest way to update ?

Comment: Backup the files and database before going for any update

Comment: How would we know if it's safe without knowing exactly which 25 plugins you're using. Off topic anyway.

Comment: Please move your question to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Backup the files and database before going for any update.
- Activate the plugin one by one and check how things going on then. It
  will help you to figure out the bugs if any.

Comment: thanks, What shoud I first update plugin or wp?

Comment: @wiramrathod you need to actually refer to the doc of those plugins ..at what version they are compatible upto..if they need latest u have to provide them latest...try with the WP update first..my opinion though and then go for the plugins ..bcoz ur site is more imp than those plugins as Wordpress upgrade also concerns about some security fixes also..so u need to fill those gaps too :)

Comment: I checked, 5 plugin update available out of 25, and 2 plugin like 'Facebook Tab Manager','JW Player Plugin for WordPres' not compatible for wp 3.5, so now I'm confuse What should I do?

Comment: @wiramrathod Most plugins don't actually break when a new version of WordPress release although it depends on wordpress upgrade changes.. i think you go with the upgrades with a correct back up of files/db

Comment: @wiramrathod chk this link for JW Player Plugin..i think they are going to release another version soon http://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-select-player-pop-up-to-embed-shortcode

Comment: @ swapnesh Thanks now I'm going to start upgrade :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21427/discussion-between-wiram-rathod-and-swapnesh)

Answer (score 0):

Not the right place for this question as it is not really programming related...
Try asking on Stack Exchanges [Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) site.

However what i would do would be to clone the install to a new sub-domain (beta.example.com) including backing up all you SQL data, install the update on the new domain, and see if everything works. If so, copy it back to the primary, or just do an install on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would wait for a while, because chances are that a few plugins will be broken by the new version (I had one break on me) until they get updated. Once you've waited for a while, you can check on the page for each plugin in the [Wordpress Plugin Directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/), which has a "Compatibility" section in the bottom-right of each plugin's description page, which tells you how many other users have reported it broken for each version.